# Odd White Space at the side of collapsed Nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav, spacing

So I'm quite inexperienced, but I'm learning. 
I've created a basic toggleable Nav using the Bootstrap framework, but when the nav collapses, there is some white space on either side of the collapsed part.
Are there some margins I'm unaware of? or is something else wrong?

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-inverse bg-inverse d-flex fixed-top">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" style="width:40px" href="#"><img class="img-fluid" id="nav-logo" src="Images/LOGO.png" width="40" height="40"></a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ml-0 bg-inverse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
        <hr/>
        <ul class="navbar-nav" style="width:100%">
            <li class="nav-item ml-md-auto mr-md-5 ml-5">
                <a class="nav-link" id="event_item" href="#">Events</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ml-md-5 ml-5">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Club</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ml-md-auto mr-md-5 ml-5">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Below is the output of the code above. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbAxV.jpg
Here is the only CSS I'm using.

```
a.nav-link {
    font-size:1.5rem;
}
nav {
    height:60px;
}
hr {
    border-color:white;
    border-width:1px;
    margin:20px, auto, auto, auto;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    width:80%;
}
body {
    font-family:"Raleway", sans-serif;
}
html, body {
    padding:0;
}
```

Here is a CodePen
https://codepen.io/JangTog/pen/zpPEom

```css
a.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-left: 80px;
}

nav {
  height: 60px;
}

.navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-brand {
  width: 40px;
}

hr.hr {
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 80%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/navStyle.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/mainStyle.css" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="max-width: 500px;">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-inverse bg-inverse fixed-top">

    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler" aria-controls="navbarToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="img-fluid" id="nav-logo" src="https://www.placehold.it/40x40" width="40" height="40"></a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ml-0 bg-inverse" id="navbarToggler">

      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item ml-md-auto">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <hr class="hidden-md-up hr" />
        <li class="nav-item ml-md-5">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Events</a>
        </li>
        <hr class="hidden-md-up hr" />
        <li class="nav-item ml-md-5">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Club</a>
        </li>
        <hr class="hidden-md-up hr" />
        <li class="nav-item ml-md-auto mr-md-5">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
<!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: I believe I did, I've added body {margin:0;} to the css, but it makes no difference. (as well as html)

Comment: I also couldn't see any margins on the chrome developer tool when highlighting all elements that could cause the problem.

Comment: You could improve this question a great deal if you find a way to reproduce or demonstrate the issue in an embedded code snippet (look for the `<>` icon in your editor toolbar for the code snippet tool) or an external link (like JSFiddle or CodePen), preferably an embedded code snippet though, it's better to contain all relevant code within the problem statement itself, it's also better for other readers and allows for a much more user-friendly method to copy the code to an answer.

Comment: Added CodePen, sorry I'm unaware of these things, thank you.

Comment: Ah don't sweat the small things :) If you ever have another question here on SO you need to ask, you'll know how to post one that receives the attention, and valuable responses, in the time it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider removing the *left* and *right* `padding` properties declared on the containing (parent) element `.fixed-top`, e.g:

**Remove `padding` on containing element:**

```
nav.fixed-top {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

It's these property values that are preventing the dropdown element from occupying the full horizontal width.

Then offset that initial padding spacing by declaring the necessary `margin` properties on the appropriate nested elements, e.g:

**Declare `margin` properties on nested elements:**

```
.navbar-brand {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.navbar-toggler-right {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
a.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-left: 80px;
}

nav {
  height: 60px;
}

.navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-brand {
  width: 40px;
}

hr.hr {
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 80%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Additional */

nav.fixed-top {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.navbar-toggler-right {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/navStyle.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/mainStyle.css" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="max-width: 500px;">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-inverse bg-inverse fixed-top">

    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler" aria-controls="navbarToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="img-fluid" id="nav-logo" src="https://www.placehold.it/40x40" width="40" height="40"></a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ml-0 bg-inverse" id="navbarToggler">

      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item ml-md-auto">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <hr class="hidden-md-up hr" />
        <li class="nav-item ml-md-5">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Events</a>
        </li>
        <hr class="hidden-md-up hr" />
        <li class="nav-item ml-md-5">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Club</a>
        </li>
        <hr class="hidden-md-up hr" />
        <li class="nav-item ml-md-auto mr-md-5">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
<!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```